# SQL Server cluster install issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008

I am going to install SQL Server 2008 Enterprise cluster on Windows Server 2008. I am wondering whether I have to setup a Windows domain (or active directory) in order to install SQL Server cluster?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some great articles here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179410.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189134.aspx

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1687

Comment: I have read some installation document. But my question is not about the process to install, but the planning (to check pre-requisite software). Do I have to install Windows domain (or active directory) in order to install SQL Server cluster?

Comment: Please read this link: http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5157575.html

Comment: Maybe this will help as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189910.aspx

Comment: @Ardman, I did not find answer to my question. It said "domain", but I do not find whether it (Windows domain or Active Directory) is a must or not?

Comment: And my initiative is to keep the installation environment and dependencies as simple as possible, if it is not a must to install Windows Domain or Active Directory, I want to skip the installtion process to make my environment as simple as possible.

Comment: But, I believe that you will need to install a Domain plus Active Directory in order for the SQL Cluster to work.

Comment: Why I need to install Domain plus Active Directory in order for the SQL Cluster to work? What features are utilized from Domain plus Active Directory?

Comment: Please read: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Agxs7TaRzv8J:download.microsoft.com/download/3/b/5/3b51a025-7522-4686-aa16-8ae2e536034d/Overview%2520of%2520Failover%2520Clustering%2520with%2520Windows%2520Server%25202008.doc+windows+server+2008+clustering&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk
There is a Word document at the top.

Comment: Sorry, this document is about Windows Server 2008 cluster, not SQL Server cluster.

Comment: Without the Windows Server 2008 clustering, how do you expect SQL Server to cluster?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 is based on Windows Server 2008 clustering, is it a must?

Comment: If you don't have a cluster service to build on top of, I don't see how SQL will manage a cluster.

Comment: So, 1. I can understand in this way, SQL Server cluster is based on Windows cluster, and Windows cluster is based on Windows Domain? 2. What functions of Windows Domain are utilized for Windows cluster?

Comment: I think that this link will provide the answers you need:
http://blogs.msdn.com/clustering/archive/2008/05/10/8483427.aspx